# How to Remove a Filter from the Admin List Table?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, actions

[image]

I don't want the "Registered customer" filter option for the Admin Orders page.

I have tried to search for how to remove it. I have been inside the WooCommerce codes to see how it's implemented.

And I can see that it's implemented inside the class `WC_Admin_List_Table_Orders` which extends `WC_Admin_List_Table`. The `WC_Admin_List_Table_Orders` class is located in:

> /woocommerce/includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-orders.php

From the `_construct` method in `WC_Admin_List_Table` there is an `add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', array( $this, 'restrict_manage_posts' ) );`.

So in `WC_Admin_List_Table_Orders` we'll find an `restrict_manage_posts` method calling the next method `render_filter()`:

```
/**
 * See if we should render search filters or not.
 */
public function restrict_manage_posts() {
    global $typenow;

    if ( in_array( $typenow, wc_get_order_types( 'order-meta-boxes' ), true ) ) {
        $this->render_filters();
    }
}

/**
 * Render any custom filters and search inputs for the list table.
 */
protected function render_filters() {
    $user_string = '';
    $user_id     = '';

    if ( ! empty( $_GET['_customer_user'] ) ) { // phpcs:disable  WordPress.Security.NonceVerification.NoNonceVerification
        $user_id = absint( $_GET['_customer_user'] ); // WPCS: input var ok, sanitization ok.
        $user    = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );

        $user_string = sprintf(
            /* translators: 1: user display name 2: user ID 3: user email */
            esc_html__( '%1$s (#%2$s &ndash; %3$s)', 'woocommerce' ),
            $user->display_name,
            absint( $user->ID ),
            $user->user_email
        );
    }
    ?>
    <select class="wc-customer-search" name="_customer_user" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Filter by registered customer', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" data-allow_clear="true">
        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user_id ); ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( wp_kses_post( $user_string ) ); // htmlspecialchars to prevent XSS when rendered by selectWoo. ?><option>
    </select>
    <?php
}
```

So, the question now is just how to prevent any of these to be called. I like that there is an add_action hook included in the process. Cause that usually means that there's possible to use `remove_action()`. And that's what I have tried to do. Without success.

**What Iv'e tried:**

Following example with both **WC_Admin_List_Table** and **WC_Admin_List_Table_Orders**:

```
remove_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', array( 'WC_Admin_List_Table', 'restrict_manage_posts' ) );
```

Above but with priority with everything from **10** to **9999999**:

```
remove_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', array( 'WC_Admin_List_Table', 'restrict_manage_posts' ), 10 );
```

**Wrapping it to wp_loaded** with a $wc_admin_post_types global variable. Found this from an online search. I also tried with another global variable, $wc_list_table. Tried it both with and without priority in the end:

```
add_action('wp_loaded', function() {
    global $wc_admin_post_types;
    remove_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', array($wc_admin_post_types, 'restrict_manage_posts'), 10, 2 );
});
```

And I have also tried with `woocommerce_loaded` and `woocommerce_init`. I have also tried above examples inside these init and loaded actions.

**Nothing works.**

Does anyone knows how to do?

Comment: Have you checked the answer? Did it work?

Comment: @SallyCJ Sorry for the late respond! It works great! Apparently it was a little bit too complicated for me to figure out by myself. But when I see your answer I do somehow understand. And the solution, the code you did is so simple. I like that, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! And actually, the answer is basically saying, "use the global `$wc_list_table` to disable the filter; but make sure `$wc_list_table` is an instance of the `WC_Admin_List_Table_Orders` class". :) (And you may also want to check if the current screen's ID is `edit-shop_order`. See [`get_current_screen()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can see that it's implemented inside the class
>   `WC_Admin_List_Table_Orders` which extends `WC_Admin_List_Table`.

Yes, that's correct.

And the orders list table is setup via [`WC_Admin_Post_Types::setup_screen()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Admin_Post_Types.html#71-108) where the method is called via these hooks: (see [`WC_Admin_Post_Types::__construct()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Admin_Post_Types.html#35-37))

```php
// Load correct list table classes for current screen.
add_action( 'current_screen', array( $this, 'setup_screen' ) );
add_action( 'check_ajax_referer', array( $this, 'setup_screen' ) );
```

And in that `setup_screen()` method, the list table is instantiated like so where the instance is put into a global variable — `$wc_list_table`:

```php
include_once 'list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-orders.php';
$wc_list_table = new WC_Admin_List_Table_Orders();
```

So you can remove the filter like so:

```php
// Be sure to rename this function..
function my_func() {
    global $wc_list_table;
    if ( $wc_list_table instanceof WC_Admin_List_Table_Orders ) {
        remove_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', array( $wc_list_table, 'restrict_manage_posts' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'current_screen', 'my_func', 11 );
add_action( 'check_ajax_referer', 'my_func', 11 );
```

Tried and tested working on WooCommerce 3.6.2.

Comment: PS: You can also check if the ID of the current screen is 'edit-shop_order'.