# How do I remove an action hook inside a class that is called by another class?

Tags: php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, actions

Okay, so I am using the "[FooEvents for WooCommerce](https://www.fooevents.com/fooevents-for-woocommerce/)" plugin for making WooCommerce products to events.

And now **I wanna replace their WooCommerce hook** `'woocommerce_order_status_completed'`  with my own.

Their hook is placed in their class and method: `FooEvents_Woo_Helper::_constructor()`

And that class (`FooEvents_Woo_Helper`) is only called by a private variable, `$this->WooHelper` in another class, their "main class" `FooEvents`.

So `FooEvents_Woo_Helper` is called inside `FooEvents` public method `plugin_init()`:

```
//WooHelper
require_once($this->Config->classPath.'woohelper.php');
$this->WooHelper = new FooEvents_Woo_Helper($this->Config);
```

Now, I learned in another question I asked earlier about a similar question, here: [How to Remove a Filter from the Admin List Table?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/337590/how-to-remove-a-filter-from-the-admin-list-table)

And I tried to do the same thing here, in different ways. But I can't make it to work. What am I doing wrong?:

```
function my_own_init() {
    global $FooEvents;

    if ( $FooEvents instanceof FooEvents ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', array( $FooEvents->WooHelper, 'process_order_tickets' ) );

    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_own_init', 11 );
```

Comment: To remove an non-static action from a class you need to pass the same instance that was originally hooked. This is `$this->WooHelper`, but because it's assigned to `$this` inside `FooEvents` you need to access that same instance of `FooEvents`, but you can only do that if it's instantiated into a global variable. How is it instantiated in the plugin?

Comment: @JacobPeattie FooEvents is instantiated as `$FooEvents` and is accessable as a global variable. But the `$WooHelper` variable inside the `FooEvents` class is private.

Comment: I'm afraid you're out of luck then. The original instance of the class that's hooked is inaccessible to you, so cannot be removed. You're not doing anything wrong, it just appears that for all intents and purposes FooEvents does not support removing this action.

Comment: can be done by accessing global `$wp_filter`, for eample see this `remove_class_filter` function: https://wpforthewin.com/remove-hook-from-class-based-wp-plugin/